# hashmap not hold values?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

In the following code, if  jcbValue evaluates to Find, I have it set to print the contents of the hashmap. It is returning NULL. I am assuming this means that by that point the contents of the hashmap have been emptied.

My questions are as follows;
1) What am I doing wrong?
2) How do I fix it?

Thanks,
CJ

```
   public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        HashMap<String, ArrayList> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList>();

        String jcbValue = (String) jcbIDF.getSelectedItem();
        if (jcbValue == "Insert") {

            String Id = jtfId.getText();
            ArrayList<String> ValueList = new ArrayList<String>();
            String Name = jtfName.getText();
            String GPA = jtfGPA.getText();
            ValueList.add(Name);
            ValueList.add(GPA);
            map.put(Id, ValueList);
            System.out.println(map);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Inserted",
                    "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            // jtfId.setText("");
            // jtfName.setText("");
            // jtfGPA.setText("");
        } else if (jcbValue == "Delete") {
            System.out.println(map);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Delete Selected; But Not Implemented", "Result",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        } else if (jcbValue == "Find") {
            System.out.println(map);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "Find Selected; But not Implemented", "Result",
                    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }// Terminates actionPerformed Class
    }// Terminates ButtonListenerClass
```

Comment: what do you want to see? what should be the output? what are you expacting? i mean, you are creating a new map and call System.out.println(map)...

Comment: First: use [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), your code is a complete clutter. Second: What is null? The output in the console?

Comment: Why don't you put `System.out.println("ID: " + Id + " Name: " + Name + " GPA: " + GPA");` before inserting them and see what they show. Chances are that will tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @ThomasJ A complete clutter? How so? I see one String out of place (in the last showMessageDialog). Other than that he's simply not indenting for the class and its terminator, which is actually a fairly common practice.

Comment: I think the output in the console should be {}... or?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're creating a new map every time you hit actionPerformed, so nothing will ever persist across calls to it.

The map needs to exist as something other than a local variable in the action handler.

(And as AVD says, your comparison is incorrect.)

Comment: I knew it was something along these lines. Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Sure thing--it's always something! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` method.

```
if(jcbValue.equals("Insert"))
{
  //
}
```

Comment: There's no `equal()` method for `String` in Java. Surely you meant `equals()`

Comment: Good to know, I will change. Thank you for the quick response!